# Keras binary classification model's AUC score doesn't increase

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

I have a imbalanced dataset which has 57000 zeros and 2500 ones. I gave class weights as an input to my model, tried to change optimizers, tried to resize number of layers and neurons. Finally I stick to ;

[image]

because it was the only one that seems systematic, tried to change layer weight regularization rules but nothing helped me yet. I am not talking about just for my validation AUC score, even train success doesn't rise satisfyingly.

Here is how I declared my model, don't mind if you think the problem is layer and node sizes. I think I tried everything that sounds sensible.

```
class_weight = {0: 23.59,
            1: 1.}

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(33, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)))
model.add(Dense(28, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4),bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)))

opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['AUC'])

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=600,verbose=1,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),class_weight=class_weight)
```

After approximate 100 epoch, it was stuck at 0.73-0.75 auc, doesn't rise anymore. I couldn't even overfit my model

Comment: I don't see why you need to add the regularizers at every layer for this model. Also I would suggest you have a pyramid structure for the number of neurons in the network. Having more neurons at the start then going deeper you would have less neurons. You could also try using a different optimizer such as Adam.

Comment: @yudhiesh Thank you I took a note about it, will try. the reason why I added regularizers at each layer is that I just wanted to see what happens if I do that way. is pyramid structure recommended ? I did not see it that often.

Comment: IMO you are abusing regularization terms and LR seems a bit high.

Comment: @Frightera I used less often at first, for sure. Did not change anything.

Comment: @yudhiesh as your comments, a changed a bit my model. Edited first post, let me see what happens, I will hit you up

Comment: @SametSökel also change the optimizer to Adam with a learning_rate of 0.001.

Comment: @yudhiesh I did, it's the first time I see 0.83 auc on my train set. what would you suggest me for the same effect on my validation set ? it looks stuck at 0.55 for last 200 epoch.

Comment: I would remove the regularizer on the sigmoid layer and add Dropout somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I would not use L1-L2 regularization unless I can't avoid overfitting with a dropout rate 0.5 - 0.6

Comment: I separately did what you both said. First I added a dropout after 3rd layer with 0.2 rate, in that case my validation score stuck at 0.55 for almost 1000 epoch. Then I increased dropout rate to 0.5 to make using L1-L2 regularization more sensible, my validation score started from 0.70 but dramatically went down (train score also). You may offer me that shrinking training when 0.70 test validation score occurs, I tried it already. The real data that I need to predict classes has 20k zeros and 20k ones. By shrinking, it only predicts 2k of ones.